# How to print List<>

Tags: c#, list

```
public void StorageList()
    { 
        int counter = 0;
        List<StorageItems> storageitems = new List<StorageItems>();
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 40.0, to_value = 80.0, amount = 49.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 81.0, to_value = 200.0, amount = 63.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 201.0, to_value = 2000.0, amount = 126.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 2001.0, to_value = 4000.0, amount = 189.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 4001.0, to_value = 20000.0, amount = 252.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 20001.0, to_value = 40000.0, amount = 315.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 40001.0, to_value = 200000.0, amount = 472.0 });
        storageitems.Add(new StorageItems() { from_value = 200001.0, to_value = 200001.0, amount = 630.0 });
        int listrow = storageitems.Count();
        while (counter <= listrow)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(storageitems[counter].amount);
            counter++;
        }

    }
```

I Just want to print all the amounts inside storageitems.
but I got an error **An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred**

Comment: while (counter < listrow)  <-- try this

Comment: @TimChang How does that solve the exception?

Comment: OP: The code you've supplied doesn't produce the exception you're seeing. Perhaps something in the `StorageItems` constructor is causing it?

Comment: On which line do you get the exception? And how is `StorageItems` defined?

Comment: Can you pleasse add definition for `StorageItems`? Cause on the first look there is no reason for `StackOverflow`, only for `IndexOutOfRange`

Comment: @TangubCityFireStation Please provide it as an edit to your question. Also, you seem to be calling `StorageList()` from the `StorageItems` constructor, and you're calling the `StorageItems` constructor from inside `StorageList()`. Therefore, you call `StorageItems` ctor which calls `StorageList()`, which calls `StorageItems` ctor, which calls `StorageList()`, which calls `StorageItems` ctor, which calls `StorageList()`, which calls `StorageItems` ctor, which calls `StorageList()`, which calls `StorageItems` ctor, which calls `StorageList()`, etc.

Comment: You are calling your method `StorageList()` in the constructor of `StorageItems` - then it is clear that you get infinite recursion.

Comment: code and the mentioned exception do not match. It should throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException not Overflow exception. Btw, if you're using List collection, then why this imperative while loop when you've ForEach  extensions in c#.

Comment: Why not [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)?

Comment: Storageitems.foreach(i=>Console.WriteLine(i.amount)) may work

Answer (score 2):

1. `IndexOutOfRange`

if a list count = 3

it's mean only list[0] & list[1] & list[2] have value,

max elemet is list[ count -1 ]

so list[3] <--- it is index out of range

so you can change to

```
While(counter < listrow) {}
```

or just use for loop like is

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.count ;i++)
{
 //...
}
```

2. `stackoverflow`

```
    public StorageItems() { StorageList(); } <--
```

and StorageList() also new StorageList();

So it can't stop. over and over to create StorageList() until stack over flow.

Comment: Or even a foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using `foreach` loop for easing the loop logic without dealing with the counter.

Method 1:

```
foreach (var item in storageitems) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.amount);
}
```

Or

Method 2 (Lambda Expression):

```
storageitems.ForEach(x => 
{
    Console.WriteLine(x.amount);
});
```

Thus, these 2 statements can be removed as no longer need.

```
int counter = 0;
int listrow = storageitems.Count();
```

With this method, will be safe in dealing with:

- IndexOutOfRange issue by passing invalid index to the list
- NullReferenceException by accessing the list when it is null